# offline synchronization of http requests iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, offline-caching

I want to implement mechanism where if there is no network connection i want to store the request in sqlite databased in iphone. Once network is available, i want to execute request from sqlite database and then clear the entry from sqlite database.

Storing information in sqlite database is fine.

Now i want to continuously check that if there are any request in database and if there are any request in database then execute the request and delete the same record from database? How i can do this effectively?

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,

Jim.

Answer (score 0):

Put a notification with the use of ios Reachability class

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handleNetworkChange:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
   reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
  [reachability startNotifier];
```

With its use you can get the callbacks whenever network is reachable and you can check for pending request and execute them.

Comment: Reachability is fine. I can do that. My main question is how to process multiple events from sqlite in different thread and then delete the processed request from sqlite?

Comment: Take every request in an array , process the first request. After getting successful response  , update/delete the request from array and sqlite. Process the second request like this